# Copiar objeto OutputStream para um arquivo

Tags: java, java-ee, spring, input-output

Confesso que é a primeira vez que trabalho com *Stream's* e *File* em *Java*.

Atualmente uso o *Spring* (*Core*) em minha aplicação, logo utilizo um recurso utilitário simples de copia de *stream's* e *file's* chamado `FileCopyUtils` (não sei se ele satisfaz a minha exigência!).

Bem, a questão é que tenho um método que tem como objetivo obter uma imagem que encontra-se em um diretório temporário (Ex:. */tem/joocebox-img/destination/MINHA_
IMG.jpg*) e grava dentro de uma pasta na máquina (Ex:. */app/joocebox-img/.../MINHA_IMG.jpg*). Abaixo segue o método para ilustrar melhor com os comentários para facilitar o entendimento:

```java
public void copyThumbnailFilesToServer(String subdomain, String oldPath, String destinationName, String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    //Subdomain: O sub-domínio corrente na aplicação (estou usando multi tenancy)
    // oldPath: Caminho da minha imagem dentro do diretorio /tmp
    //destinationName e fileName: atributos usados para montar o caminho onde o arquivo deve ser salvo

    //folder: usado na condicional if para verificar se a pasta onde será persistida a imagem (caso o caminho exista)
    File folder = new File(new JooceBoxProperties().getPathThumbnailImage(subdomain) + destinationName);

    //chamada de um metodo que realiza o resize da minha imagem retornando um OutputStream
    OutputStream resizeDestinationImageToThumb = resizeDestinationImageToThumb(oldPath);

    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdirs();

        //Aqui é onde estou perdido. Preciso encontrar um modo (não necessariamente com o FileCopyUtils) de gravar o resizeDestinationImageToThumb dentro de um arquivo. 
        FileCopyUtils.copy(FileUtils.openInputStream(new File(oldPath)), resizeDestinationImageToThumb);

    } else {

        FileCopyUtils.copy(FileUtils.openInputStream(new File(oldPath)), resizeDestinationImageToThumb);
    }
}
```

A dificuldade básica está descrita acima. Se for necessário eu posso postar os métodos de *resize* de imagem, afim de talvez melhorar algo.

### EDIÇÃO

Tentei utilizar a abordagem do `ImageIO.write();`, mas sem sucesso como mostrado abaixo:

```java
public void copyThumbnailFilesToServer(String subdomain, String oldPath, String destinationName, String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    File folder = new File(new JooceBoxProperties().getPathThumbnailImage(subdomain) + destinationName);
    FileUtils.touch(new File(new JooceBoxProperties().getPathThumbnailImage(subdomain) + destinationName + "/" + fileName));

    OutputStream resizeDestinationImageToThumb = resizeDestinationImageToThumb(oldPath);

    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdirs();
        //FileCopyUtils.copy(FileUtils.openInputStream(new File(oldPath)), resizeDestinationImageToThumb);
        ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) resizeDestinationImageToThumb, "jpg", new File(new JooceBoxProperties().getPathThumbnailImage(subdomain) + destinationName + "/" + fileName));
    } else {
        ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) resizeDestinationImageToThumb, "jpg", new File(new JooceBoxProperties().getPathThumbnailImage(subdomain) + destinationName + "/" + fileName));
        //FileCopyUtils.copy(FileUtils.openInputStream(new File(oldPath)), resizeDestinationImageToThumb);
    }
}
```

Ele não realiza a cópia dos bytes para o arquivo criado.

Comment: Você está usando `CommonsIO`? Aquele `FileUtils` é dela?

Comment: Sim pertence o *FileUtils* pertence ao *CommonsIO* do apache @rrnan

Comment: Se não me engano ela tem um método que serve justamente para o que está precisando. `FileUtils.copyFile(source, destino);`, ambos os parâmetros são `File`.

Comment: Então, existe uma classe do *CommonsIO* chamada *ImageIO*. Editei a pergunta utilizando ela, mas ainda não consegui o resultado esperado.

Comment: Será que o seu `folder.mkdirs();` não está falhando? Este método é `boolean`, e você deveria verificar se ele retorna `true`.

Comment: Ah, e por sinal, você pode colocar o `ImageIO.write(blablabla);` depois do bloco `if` para evitar ter que repeti-lo no `else`. Assim fica mais fácil de entender. Deixe dentro do bloco `if` apenas o `mkdirs`.

Comment: Bem observado @Victor :)

Answer (score 1):

Bem, consegui "bolar" uma solução alterando o retorno do meu método de *resize* de imagens (`resizeDestinationImageToThumb()`) para um *array* de *byte's*. Logo a classe utilitária do *Spring* `FileCopyUtils.copy(byte[] in, File out);` me ajudou na copia do arquivo. Abaixo como foi solucionado:

```
public void copyThumbnailFilesToServer(String subdomain, String oldPath, String destinationName, String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    File folder = new File(new JooceBoxProperties().getPathThumbnailImage(subdomain)+destinationName);
    FileUtils.touch(new File(new JooceBoxProperties().getPathThumbnailImage(subdomain)+destinationName+"/"+fileName));

    if (!folder.exists())
        folder.mkdirs();

    FileCopyUtils.copy(resizeDestinationImageToThumb(oldPath), new File(new JooceBoxProperties().getPathThumbnailImage(subdomain)+destinationName+"/"+fileName));
}
```